# Why is PHP adding `target="_blank"` to my HTML emails?

Tags: php, html, email

I have a PHP script that writes out an HTML email that includes two links. One link is just a regular URL for a web site. The other is for iPhone users to connect directly to the app. The code looks something like this:

```
$mailLinkA = '<a href="http://www.mysite.com">web link text</a>';
$mailLinkB = '<a href="myappname://?variable">iphone app link text</a>';
```

But, when the mail arrives, the links are all totally munged.

In the case of the mail link, this additional `target="_blank"` text being added, but in such a way that it is destroying the syntax and breaking the link:

```
<a target="_blank" ="http://www.mysite.com">web link text</a>
```

In the case of the iPhone app link, everything in the  link tag is being stripped out, leaving a malformed  tag:

```
<a>web link text</a>
```

In all the years I've been working with PHP, I've never seen such behaviour, and never heard of `target="_blank"`, so I was totally surprised when I looked it up on Google and found link after link of people asking how to *include* it. So I'm totally baffled.

Maybe `target="_blank"` is something I should or should not have in my link. But I think it should be me who adds it in if I decide to, not some default inclusion that is stomping all over my code.

Further, why is my iPhone link being simply destroyed?

How do I get control of this behaviour and have PHP just let me put in links and not try and mess with them?

Comment: `target="_blank"` means that a new window will be opened to go to the page. As to why it is messing with your href attribute I have no idea! Have you tried just adding it yourself to see if the mail program will stop futzing around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every mail service Hotmail / Gmail or software like Outlook will redefine your HTML, and one logic issue is to put the target _blank so that is loaded in another tab/window and not in the tab of the mail service. It is usual for the server to change HTML, that's why is a fuzz to program mail templates to be compatible with for example Outlook.

Comment: So you're saying that it's not the PHP server doing this, but the email web client?

Comment: @Dave M G: yes of course, this is simply what makes you want to hit your head against the wall hehe. Advice: never think PHP invents code you are providing literally, think always there is a third-party issue, call it Outlook, or call it Firefox etc

Answer (score 0):

In which email website you are getting the email from your code. Because many email providers like gmail, hotmail etc. changes any link to the "target=_blank".
So, this is the usual.